# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET при получении ответа на ajax запрос

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь отправить ajax запрос:

```
 $.ajax({
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type : 'get',
    url : 'order/get/'+i,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {},
    success : function(result) {
        alert("Successfully!");
    },
    error : function(result, status, er) {
        alert("error: "+result+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }
});
```

Метод который принимает его:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrder(
        @PathVariable("id") long id) {
    Order order = orderService.getOrderById(id);
    if (order == null) {
        new ResponseEntity<Order>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Order>(order, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Запрос обрабатывается и возвращается  значение, но в клиенте возникает ошибка:

> GET net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Все что извесно об ошибке это:

> X-Requested-With
>   result = Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}, status = "error", er = ""}

Comment: Функция в error срабатывает? Смотрели в содержимое запроса и ответа от сервера в инструментах разработчика браузера в раздели сеть?

Comment: В интернетах пишут, что это связано с сертификатами. У вас сайт на https?

Comment: @lampa сайт на http и работает на локальном сервере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что сущность Order сериализовалась в JSON всести со всеми атрибутами, в том числе с теми, которые позначены @ManyToOne. Такая сериализация была излишняя и Json ответ был очень огромный. В классе сущности Order, нужно было обозначить такие атрибуты аннотацией @JsonIgnore. После это ошибка пропала и ответ обрабатывается нормально.